# DropDownList asp.net mvc 3 problems

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i Show a data in the DropDownList:(im usign datacontext)

Controller:

var query = newdb.Incident.Select(c => new { c.ID, c.Name });
ViewBag.items = new SelectList(query.AsEnumerable(), "ID", "Name");

View:

@Html.DropDownList("items", (SelectList) ViewBag.items, "--Select a Incident--")

Problem:

i want to know how i can select a item from the DropDownlist and  send a parameter back to the controller of the item selected, because i try this and dont work:

@using (Html.BeginForm("er", "er", FormMethod.Post, new { id = 4  })){

@Html.DropDownList("items", (SelectList) ViewBag.items, "--Select a Incident--")}

i hope somebody can helpLaughing

Comment: See my tutorial [Working with the DropDownList Box and jQuery][1] and [My blog Cascading DropDownList in ASP.Net MVC][2]
  [1]: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/javascript/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/using-the-dropdownlist-helper-with-aspnet-mvc
  [2]: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/01/09/cascasding-dropdownlist-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You could pass the selected value as 4th argument of the SelectList constructor:

```
var query = newdb.Incident.Select(c => new { c.ID, c.Name }); 
ViewBag.items = new SelectList(query.AsEnumerable(), "ID", "Name", "4");
```

and also in your view make sure that you are using a different value as first argument to the DropDownList helper because right now you are using `"items"` which is wrong, because the first argument represents the name of the generated dropdownlist that will be used back in the controller to fetch the selected value:

```
@Html.DropDownList(
    "selectedIncidentId", 
    (SelectList) ViewBag.items, 
    "--Select a Incident--"
)
```

Also I would recommend you using view models and the strongly typed version of the DropDownListFor helper:

```
public class IncidentsViewModel
{
    public int? SelectedIncidentId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Incidents { get; set; }
}
```

and then:

```
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    var incidents = newdb.Incident.ToList().Select(c => new SelectListItem
    { 
        Value = c.ID.ToString(), 
        Text = c.Name 
    }); 
    var model = new IncidentsViewModel
    {
        SelectedIncidentId = 4, // preselect an incident with id = 4
        Incidents = incidents
    }
    return View(model);
}
```

and in your strongly typed view:

```
@model IncidentsViewModel
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(
        x => x.SelectedIncidentId, 
        Model.Incidents, 
        "--Select a Incident--"
    )

    <button type="submit">OK</button>
}
```

Comment: or you could follow my tutorial/blog See my tutorial [Working with the DropDownList Box and jQuery][1] and [My blog Cascading DropDownList in ASP.Net MVC][2]
  [1]: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/javascript/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/using-the-dropdownlist-helper-with-aspnet-mvc
  [2]: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2012/01/09/cascasding-dropdownlist-in-asp-net-mvc.aspx